# Android: changing the pressed/focused ressource by code

Tags: android, focus, selected, pressed

I am using some tweaks that allow the user to change the UI of my application with ressources from their SDCard. That's really easy and nothing special, I just use the "setImageDrawable" or "setImageBitmap".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

That's really cool and all my users are happy to customize the UI.

But now, I would like to also change the pressed/focused ressource of the button!

Now, when they click on it, they cannot see anything and they click maybe 10 times. And more problematic, that's not really intuitive.

So i would like to change also the pressed/focused state programmatically...

Ani idea suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to make all of your ImageButtons have a StateListDrawable instead of BitmapDrawables.

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
StateListDrawable sl = new StateListDrawable();
sl.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled }, yourDefaultDrawableHere);
sl.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_selected }, yourImageDrawableHere);
ib.setImageDrawable(sl);
```